# Is it possible to handle cell phone calls through a Samsung Galaxy Player?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, bluetooth, calls, samsung-galaxy-player

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy Player 4.2 running Android 2.3.5 Gingerbread. I was wondering if there was anyway to sync my cell phone to it via Bluetooth and then handle all of my calls and texts through the Galaxy Player.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. So far managed to sync to my nokia C3 phone and it seems to make calls OK but if a call comes in the whole lot locks up and I can't do anything. The phone seems to think the 4.2 is a headset rater than a handsfree.